# ldap filter for group membership

Tags: ldap

I need help with an LDAP filter to retrieve group membership. My goal is as follows:
Say i need to retrieve group membership (direct/nested) for generic AD server [Thus, i cannot use MS-AD customized LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN to achieve my goal]. Hence, this is what i am  planning:
Say user A is direct member of group A, B, C. Internally A's memberOf attribute is D and B's memberOf attribute is E, and C's memberOf is F. So, is there a way in a single LDAP query can i query for the membership attribute for all the 3 groups A, B, C to retrieve information related to D, E, F and so on.

If there is any such LDAP filter, can someone help me.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Marc for pointing to this. I humbly accept my mistake but i am actually quite naive with respect to the complete website etiquette and culture. I accept my mistake and apologize for the same. Please can you let me know how can i accept the answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure if you can get a direct query for this. I can only think of a nested ldap query.

Comment: Any inputs on what the nested ldap query i could make use of here?